# Timed content and flagging content as viewed by user?

Tags: plugins, content, user-access

I'm trying to put together a site with membership functionality and i'm having most of what i need together. However, what's still missing in the mix are two things:

1. I need to be able to display content starting from a certain date and stop displaying it starting from a certain date (or give it an expiration time).
2. I'd like to be able to have content flagged as viewed by individual users so i can then display it in a different section of the site for that user. How that's done (if via taxonomies or whatever) i don't really care and the 'putting it somewhere else' i can do myself.

Are there any good, simple (do one thing only, but do it right), free plugins that cater for the above?

Answer (score 2):

there are some plugins to achieve what you are trying:

[Post Expirator](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/post-expirator/) - Allows you to add an expiration date (minute) to posts which you can configure to either delete the post or change it to a draft.

[Simple Expires](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-expires/) - Enable Posts and Pages to automatically expire and change at a certain time, and provide notification of expiration.

as for the second part of your question,

> I'd like to be able to have content
>   flagged as viewed by individual users
>   so i can then display it in a
>   different section of the site for that
>   user.

you can do that by simply adding a new usermeta field that will contain an array of post ids like so

```
function my_user_flag_887($post_id){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $user_flags = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'flaged', false);
        $user_flags[] = $post_id;
        update_user_meta($current_user->ID , 'flaged', $user_flags);
    }
}
```

so all you have to do is call that function and pass the post_id to add/flag

```
my_user_flag_887('43');
```

and assuming that the user is logged in it will add the ID 43 to the users flag array.

and you can check to see if a user has flagged a post by simply checking if it in that array or even better you can use wp_query to select posts that are not in that array:

```
global $current_user;
        get_currentuserinfo();
        $user_flags = get_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'flaged', false);
    $my_q = new WP_Query(array('post__not_in' => $user_flags ));
    if ($my_q->have_posts()){
        while ( $my_q->have_posts() ) { $my_q->the_post();
            //do you loop stuff
        }
    }else{
    echo 'nothing found';
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll give that a go as soon as i get around to it and the flag your comprehensive answer.

Comment: For the second part...since this might grow a bit quickly (we'll have weekly posts to be flagged), i'm wondering if i should just create my own table instead? Which one would be more performant...passing a long array to post__not_in or joining another table with a single reference id?